# AssertionError: Incoming Tensor shape must be 4-D

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, tflearn

I'm trying to make a classifier and I keep getting this error which is really confusing to me. As I'm really new to machine learning stuff I can't find anything to internet for this.

**ERROR**

```
AssertionError: Incoming Tensor shape must be 4-D
```

**Code**

```
IMG_SIZE = 64
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    convnet = input_data(shape=[1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1],name='input')
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
    convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
    convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
    model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log', tensorboard_verbose=0)
    model.fit({'input': X_train}, {'targets': y_train}, n_epoch=10,
              validation_set=({'input': X_test}, {'targets': y_test}),
              snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

if i give `convnet = input_data(shape=[None,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1],name='input')`
it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\utils.py", line 187, in slice_array
    return X[start]
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What's in your `X_train` and `y_train` variables?

Comment: @Mikhail Thank you I caught the error and answered it. But I'm facing another weird thing in this. 
`Training samples: 0
Validation samples: 1`

it doesn't work after this, obviously when the training samples are 0. But why its not taking any kind of samples. Can you answer this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The error was due to this

```
train = training_data[:-5000]
test = testing_data[-5000:]

X_train = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
#The error was here
y_train = (i[1] for i in train)

X_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
#The error was here
y_test = (i[1] for i in test)
```

After making a list in Y_train it starts working, like given below.

```
train = training_data[:-5000]

test = testing_data[-5000:]

X_train = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

y_train = [i[1] for i in train]

X_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
y_test = [i[1] for i in test]
```